# How to find ip of my Raspberry Pi with Kali Linux for first time headless way?

Tags: ssh, ip, raspberry-pi3

I need to use my Pi 3 without a desktop ,using an ethernet I connected my pi and laptop and I'm using ssh to start with Pi but how to find IP of my Pi 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a broadcast ping from your machine. So if your local machine has IP address `192.168.1.123`, then do a `ping 192.168.1.255` and see which machines answer. One of the replies should be from the Raspberry Pi.